# Load huge text buffer into QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

What is the **correct** and **optimum** way to show a huge text buffer in a `QPlainTextEdit` widget? I mean listen to scrollbar move events, and dynamically pass only the visible portion of the text to the widget, according to current scrollbar position.

I cannot send the entire buffer to the widget using [`setPlainText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#setPlainText) because the text buffer is more than 1 GB in size, and that function takes a copy of it, which doubles memory usage.

Comment: Are you trying to give only a part of the huge text in your `QPlainTextEdit` or do you want to give it the whole text and scroll at the desired position ?

Comment: @Fareanor I want it to pretend that whole buffer is loaded, and scroll at the desired position.

Comment: By _"pretend"_, you mean that in reality the `QPlainTextEdit` does not contain the full buffer ?

Comment: @Fareanor yes because content is more than 1 GB in size, which makes GUI slow and freezing (I guess), and also I want to add some coloring to the visible part of text before feeding it into the widget.

Comment: Would it be fine to just load/display eg. the 100 first lines of the file in the `QPlainTextEdit`, and then have a button `more` that users can click to load a 100 more lines in the `QPlainTextEdit` each time it is clicked?

Comment: @gpalex Not bad. I am searching for alternatives. What I want is a hex editor like the 010 Editor: https://www.sweetscape.com/graphics/010EdDarkHex.GIF

Comment: @Ali "and that function takes a copy of it, which doubles memory usage" why not deleting the original string after calling `setPlainText` since it is copied by `QPlainTextEdit` and can be retrieved via `QPlainTextEdit::toPlainText`

Comment: @Ali BTW should the text in your editor be editable or is it read-only text?

Comment: @gpalex I can go with read only for now if editable way is not easy to achieve. In the editable case, only line split (with the enter key) and joining (moving line n+1 to the end of line n with backspace key) is required.

Comment: @Ali If you want something like the editor you showed, you need a `QTableWidget` or `QTableView`, not a `QPlainTextEdit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a 1GB data and you don't want to exceed this memory load, I think you should read you data part by part and append them to the `QPlainTextEdit`'s buffer. This way, you'll never exceed your 1GB memory usage for your huge text.
Indeed, the temporary variable used to store the loaded part will be erased at each iteration and you just have to destroyed it at the end of your loop.

Moreover, if you want only the visible part to be colored in a different way (as you said in our discussion), I think you should color the whole text because only the visible part color will be displayed (as the other parts are hidden, their color does not matter).
And when you will scroll down or up, the text being already coloured as you wish, you will have no action to perform.
Consequently, you will have the desired behaviour reducing the computation overhead at the same time because you don't perform color changing tasks at each scroll event.

Here is a minimal, complete and reproducible example of what I mean:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QFile data_file("path/to/data/file/some_data.txt");
    if(!data_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return -1;

    // ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    // Set the text color
    QTextEdit view;
    view.setTextColor(Qt::darkGreen);

    // read 100 chars by 100 chars (set the value you want)
    unsigned int MAX_LEN(100);

    // Create the temporary buffer
    char * part = new char[MAX_LEN];
    // Read the file part by part
    qint64 readBytes;
    while((readBytes = data_file.read(part, MAX_LEN)) > 0)
    {
        view.insertPlainText(QString(part).left(static_cast<int>(readBytes)));
    }

    // destroy the temporary buffer
    delete[] part;
    // ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------

    data_file.close();

    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If loading the full data in the `QPlainTextEdit` slows down you GUI too much, I think you can load the data as you did and just set a part of the data in the `QPlainTextEdit`. And on scroll event, you can use [`QPlainTextEdit::textCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#textCursor) combined with [`QTextCursor::atStart()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#atStart) and [`QTextCusrsor::atEnd()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#atEnd) to detect if the user has reached the beginning or the end of the displayed part. For example, if the user has reached the end, you get the cursor position, and you use it to set the following part instead of the current one (perhaps using an overlapping section in order to make the trick smoother).

Comment: I tested it with 20 lines of text with each line containing 1 mega bytes (20 MB in total). GUI is extremely slow.

Comment: And with 200,000 lines of text (each line with 1000 characters) and wrapping enabled, it has undefined behavior. I think the widget uses int32 counter somewhere, which overflows.

Comment: @Ali Ah you are right for the color, I did not know that, I'll remove my note then. But for the slowness, I made the test with much more than 20 lines and I didn't notice this problem. But I think with your huge data, it will slow down anyway.

Comment: You will need a custom widget, and use mmap to load the text. This is a very corner case which is not covered by Qt.

Comment: @Ali I have made an edit in my answer that suggests a possible solution. Maybe a bit far-fetched but it should work.

Comment: Okay I accept it and use it, because there is no better solution that satisfies the “principle of least astonishment.” As @elcuco mentioned, I will use a modified QPlainTextEdit though it is so hard and time consuming.

Comment: @Ali Don't worry, if the proposed solution does not satisfies you, you are not required to accept one :) I hope you'll find a solution that better suits your needs then.